# Why does this print nothing in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Why does the following function call not display anything to the console in Python 3?  Does this have something to do with type hinting?

`print:("Hello, world!")`

I can't for the life of me figure out why the colon causes nothing to display but is not considered a syntax error.

Comment: Everything after the `:` is a type hint, so your statement is just `print`, which does nothing.

Comment: that's what I figured, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Everything after the `:` is a type hint, so your statement is just `print`, which does nothing.